# Jupyter notebook download button

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

I'm trying to implement a download button in jupyter notebook (`IPython`). I know that button widget do exists in jupyter like below.

```
from ipywidgets import Button

...

btn_download = widgets.Button(
    description='Download',
    button_style='', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
    tooltip='Download',
    icon='download',
    layout=button_layout )

# Then implement download in on_click 
def on_button_download_clicked(b):
    # Handle download using urlopen
    filedata = urllib.request.urlopen(r'file://' + filepath)
    datatowrite = filedata.read()
    with open("download.fid", 'wb') as f:  
        f.write(datatowrite)

# Register callback
btn_download.on_click(on_button_download_clicked)
```

However, this does not seem to work. I have tried few other methods like using `urlretrieve` and still won't work.

I am also aware that solution such as using `ipython.display.FileLink` exists, but I want to have it in form of button.

Is there any workaround in this?

Comment: Can you describe more about how it does not work? What kind of errors do you receive when you try to click the button?

Comment: @ac24 I do not encounter any error, it just doesn't do anything when I clicked. What this code does, however, is writing the `datatowrite` into `download.fid` in the server alongside the notebook. I am not sure how to pass the `datatowrite` into client (browser) connecting to the notebook. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Your function has the button instance as the first argument. You could always assign the `datawrite` variable to the button instance in the `on_button_download_clicked()` e.g. `b.file = datawrite`. Then the file should be available.

Comment: Have a look at related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61708701/how-to-download-a-file-using-ipywidget-button

Answer (score 2):

Solara has a [FileDownload component](https://solara.dev/api/file_download) that can be used for this.

```
import solara

filepath = "/Users/maartenbreddels/beach.jpeg"
data = open(filepath, "rb").read()
solara.FileDownload(data=data, label="Download image", filename="image.jpeg")
```

This looks like:

[image]

If you need this embedded in a ipywidget VBox, or HBox, use the [.widget](https://solara.dev/api/widget) method:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
widgets.VBox([
    solara.FileDownload.widget(data=data, label="Download image", filename="image.jpeg")
])
```