# How to download a file using ipywidget button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I build a ipywidget button. I hope that when the button is clicked, the program do the computing, and get a result string, then user can download the string as a file.

THe codes are like this:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets


download_button = widgets.ToggleButton()
download_button.on_click(do_some_work)

def do_some_work(content)-> str:
    res = compute()
    # Here comes the problem: how to let user download the res as a file?

def compute()-> str:
    # ... do_some_compute
    return res
```

I have read [ipywidgets doc](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html) for plenty times, but could not find a solution.

I use an alternative way now (which seriously affected the user experience): create a HTML widget and when download_button is clicked, change the value of HTML widget to an link to `data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,{res}` to let user click and download, but is there any way to achieve this with single one click?

Any help will be much appreciate.

Answer (score 13):

The most elegant way I've seen is Solution 1 [here](https://medium.com/ibm-data-science-experience/how-to-upload-download-files-to-from-notebook-in-my-local-machine-6a4e65a15767) (slightly modified and presented below):

```
from ipywidgets import HTML
from IPython.display import display

import base64

res = 'computed results'

#FILE
filename = 'res.txt'
b64 = base64.b64encode(res.encode())
payload = b64.decode()

#BUTTONS
html_buttons = '''<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<a download="{filename}" href="data:text/csv;base64,{payload}" download>
<button class="p-Widget jupyter-widgets jupyter-button widget-button mod-warning">Download File</button>
</a>
</body>
</html>
'''

html_button = html_buttons.format(payload=payload,filename=filename)
display(HTML(html_button))
```

Comment: Thank you for this! But I am not sure how much this can help me in general. In my case, the file doesn't exist when init the button, instead, it's computed after clicking the button. I am actually looking for a way to let the button trigger both of the computation and downloading.

Comment: Why encode and then decode?

Answer (score 8):

Late to the game but if anyone else faces this issue and needs dynamic file content, here is an approach for this. The code is inspired by the answer by @Poompil . Also, there might be more elegant way to bypass browser cache but could not make it to work in Jupyter.

```
import base64
import hashlib
from typing import Callable

import ipywidgets
from IPython.display import HTML, display


class DownloadButton(ipywidgets.Button):
    """Download button with dynamic content

    The content is generated using a callback when the button is clicked.
    """

    def __init__(self, filename: str, contents: Callable[[], str], **kwargs):
        super(DownloadButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.filename = filename
        self.contents = contents
        self.on_click(self.__on_click)

    def __on_click(self, b):
        contents: bytes = self.contents().encode('utf-8')
        b64 = base64.b64encode(contents)
        payload = b64.decode()
        digest = hashlib.md5(contents).hexdigest()  # bypass browser cache
        id = f'dl_{digest}'

        display(HTML(f"""
<html>
<body>
<a id="{id}" download="{self.filename}" href="data:text/csv;base64,{payload}" download>
</a>

<script>
(function download() {{
document.getElementById('{id}').click();
}})()
</script>

</body>
</html>
"""))
```

Now we can simply add

```
DownloadButton(filename='foo.txt', contents=lambda: f'hello {time.time()}', description='download')
```

which adds a download button and the contents of the downloaded file is generated when the button is clocked.

[image]

Comment: This is great - I've started to use this in my implementation(s) now. Thank you!

Comment: This works great in Jupyter but does not work in JupyterLab (tested with 3.2.5). Any idea how to make it work in JupyterLab?

Answer (score 4):

We solved this problem in Solara with the [FileDownload component](https://solara.dev/api/file_download). Solara  re-uses the whole ipywidgets stack, which means you can use it in the Jupyter notebook.

```
import solara
import time
import pandas as pd


# create a dummy dataframe with measurements
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'instrument': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'], 'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})


def my_work():
    time.sleep(3)  # mimic a long running job
    dff = df[df['values'] > 5]
    # .to_csv returns a string
    return dff.to_csv(index=False)

solara.FileDownload(data=my_work, filename="my_file.csv")
```

[image: Solara file upload component]

Note that Solara does not give you a widget by default, so if you want to embed it in a larger ipywidget application, you should use the [.widget](https://solara.dev/api/widget) method:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
widgets.VBox([
    solara.FileDownload.widget(data=my_work, filename="my_file.csv")
])
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing - this looks great: simple, yet working. Would you know whether the solara widgets work in `voila`?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, they should work out of the box since they are built on top of the ipywidget stack.